# Why does my thread not print each iteration of i, instead prints one variable multiple times

Tags: c, pthreads

```
void *phonecall(void *vargp){
        printf("%i\n",*((int *)vargp));
        return NULL;
}

int main(int argc,char **argv){
        int niters=atoi(argv[1]);
        sem_init(&lock,0,1);
        sem_init(&connect_lock,0,7);
        sem_init(&operators,0,4);
        pthread_t threads[niters];
        for(int i=0;i<niters;i++){
                pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, phonecall, (void *)&i);
        }
        for(int i=0;i<niters;i++){
                pthread_join(threads[i],NULL);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

if i enter make 2
The output often results in
2
2

I know this is the reason we use sem_wait and post but I dont understand when you create thread with id 1, why will it not get printed. Maybe the order is different of 1 and 2 but both should get printed.

In short my basic question is how does the value of vargp change to 2 because 2 threads are create with id 1 and 2 and the output of each thread is often 2 \n 2

Thank You

Comment: All your threads are given pointers to the same `i` variable. This variable is also not accessible when the loop ends, so you're getting undefined behavior.

Comment: Try passing `i` instead of `&i` (and remove the deref in `phonecall`).

Answer (score 0):

You can't be sure that threads will be executed before the next iteration. It could happen that threads are executed after the next iteration or even loop finishes before a thread is executed (in that case, as Barmar said, this variable would not be accessible anymore and you would be getting an undefined behavior).
What you can do to solve the issue is allocate memory using malloc and assign the value of i to it.
Try the following inside the first for loop:

```
    int* a = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *a = i;
    pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, phonecall, a);
```

Comment: Don't forget to free it